# Is there a particular approach to prevent CSRF/XSRF with Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, csrf

[Cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) (CSRF or XSRF) attacks provokes unauthorised actions in your web application by users you believe to be trusted.

That is surely something we would like to prevent, and I am particularly working with Zend Framework. Is there a Zend Framework approach to prevent CSRF/XSRF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. [Zend_Form_Element_Hash](http://www.zendframeworkinaction.com/2009/03/14/zend_form_element_hash-and-crsf/)

Comment: He asked about Zend Framework, so I gave him a link to a component from Zend Framework which answers his question!

Comment: Also this was the first hit I got in google for Zend_Form_Element_Hash